# Invalid type in JSON write error trying to send custom class via JSON to .NET web service

Tags: ios, json, swift, web-services, swift-class

I am trying to send data to a .NET web service that accepts three parameters whose types are (String, String, QBUser Class). In Javascript, I would send the parameters in JSON like so:

```
{sKey: "key", sUpdatetype: "edit", oQbUser: QBUser}
```

I have never had any issue with that method before and .NET would be able to sort it right into a class object on the server. With Swift, I have achieved success sending almost every type in the book so far as JSON but I am having issues sending custom classes/struct as a parameter. Here is my current code:

```
func updateQbUser(k: String, t: String, oUser: QBUUser, completion: @escaping (_ oVisits: AnyObject) -> ()) {
    let params: [String: Any] = ["sKey": k, "sUpdateType": t, "iObjectId": oUser]
    let url = URL(string: "myWebService.asmx/updateQbUser")!
    let session = URLSession.shared
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    do { request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: .prettyPrinted) } catch let error { print(error.localizedDescription) }
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
        guard error == nil else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.async { completion(response!) }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

The error as shown in the console is as follows:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (QBUUser)'
```

The QBUUser class is not an instance of NSString, NSNumber, NSArray, NSDictionary, or NSNull so I am stuck on how to get this across to the server.

Is there a way to convert the QBUUser class to Any Object type listed above before attempting to send? I tried to run a loop over the class and that was a whole different bag of hammers but got some error about could not AnyHashable over Array Literal or some such. Is there a better way I have not discovered?

The parameters have to be in that way so I am stuck there. I just need to get the class sent over to the other side as what is essentially just in a key/value pair.

here is what the class looks like printed in the console:

```
  [QBUUser]:
  ID:20786
  created at:2017-05-03 15:05:56 +0000
  updated at:2017-05-03 20:16:52 +0000
  externalUserID:2456369827
  blobID:0
  facebookID:(null)
  twitterID:(null)
  twitterDigitsID:(null)
  full name:Erik Grosskurth
  email:erik@webgraphicsatlanta.com
  login:Erik_2456369827
  phone:(null)
  tags:(
    ""
)
  lastRequestAt:2017-05-03 20:20:16 +0000
  customData:(null)
  website:(null)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You, most likely, just need to convert your `QBUUser` object into a dictionary.  You could do it inline, though if you're planning to reuse that functionality you may as well make a helper function to do it.

The dictionary should just look something like this:

```
let qbuUser = QBUUser() //presumably you already have a reference to the user in question
let user: [String : Any] = ["id" : qbuUser.ID, "createdAt" : qbuUser.createdAt, "updatedAt" : qbuUser.updatedAt, ...]
```

If you want to create a helper method in your `QBUUser` class you could do something like:

```
extension QBUUser {
   func toDictionary() -> [String : Any] {
      return ["id", self.ID, "createdAt", self.createdAt, ...]
   }
}
```

And that'd allow you to change your existing function to look like this:

```
let params: [String: Any] = ["sKey": k, "sUpdateType": t, "iObjectId": oUser.toDictionary()]
```

It also might be worth pointing out that the key for that `QBUUser` object in your parameters is "iObjectId", which (to me) implies that all they need is the `ID` from your user, which makes this entire solution moot.